# Black blocks and lines on screen

Tags: 11.10, gnome, compiz, xorg

I often get lines and blocks on screen. Some of them disappear after scrolling application window back and forth, but some of them don't.

Seems like something is wrong with screen refresh or compiz or xorg.
I'm using 11.10 x64 with gnome 3 on ASUS X54L, intel core duo B800.

Sceens of the error:

[image: http://www.mackonis.lt/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Nuotrauka-2012-01-11-154021.png]

[image]

[image: third]

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you try installing XFCE or KDE just to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Already tried that. Problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got a bug in the Intel video driver. You may want to update your Xorg from the [Xorg crack pushers repository](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa). It helped me.

Comment: Hm. The bug still seems to be there, but at least the system is USABLE now because the error appears VERY rarely and for a VERY short time.

Comment: 12.04 seems to use Sandybridge drivers which fixes the bug.

Comment: Installing x86 version of Ubuntu instead of x64 fixes the problem completely.